# What's a good resource where I can publish some narratives in a minority language?

Tags: written-language, descriptive-linguistics, american-languages, language-preservation

During my fieldwork, I recorded, transcribed and translated a dozen or so narratives in an indigenous language of Central America, in close cooperation with a couple native speakers (including some beautiful illustrations). Now we'd like to publish these narratives in an open source book --- but not necessarily (or at least not only) as a linguistics textbook.

I think lang-sci press may be too technical, I'd prefer to make this more for the community than for linguists (although hopefully both, nice that it can be in LaTeX).

I tried Mac publisher, but the interface is very annoying ... Ideally there is an opportunity (even in a vanity press) to submit in LaTeX. But maybe some of you guys have experience with this.

Comment: Blatantly not about linguistics

Comment: I vote to keep this question open: Documentation of endangered languages is definitely a task linguists do, and searching for preservation of that documentation is essential.

Comment: @Wilson blatantly not linguistics?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be about where one would put such materials (not how one would handle the typesetting issue). There are at least three places which don't require content review: Zenodo, Figshare, and the [SOAS Endangered Languages Archive](https://www.soas.ac.uk/elar/depositing-with-elar/who-can-deposit/) (I can't say for certain that the later is  appropriate, so read their material).

Answer (score 2):

Another potential archive for documentation of endangered languages is [The Language Archive](https://tla.mpi.nl/) currently hosted by the Max Planck Institute for Psycholinguistics at Nijmegen (The Netherlands).